# '>=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to do 3 slices from a list of vectors from a txt, file using conditions, I've already tried doing it using filter and list comprehensions, but they all give the same error. What is causing this error?

When I try to run it, this causes this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "teste5.py", line 25, in <module>  
vetor_xB = vetor_x[vetor_x >= 400 : X <= 500]   
TypeError:'>=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Vector_X is a list, you can’t do inequality checks on a list of numbers with another number. Did you mean to use X instead

Comment: What did you think a slice from `vetor_x >= 400` to `X <= 500` was supposed to mean?

Comment: `vetor_x` is a list as the error says, If you want to compare to the integer `400`, you  must select an element of that list to compare, like `vetor_x[0] > 400`.

Comment: @John But what if I want to compare with all the elements?

Comment: @user2357112 It should mean the elements x and y where the x's are in this range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe:

```
#Conditions
B = 0
G = 0
R = 0
for i in range(0,len(vetor_x):
    if vetor_x[i]<=500:
       vetor_xB[B] = vetor_x[i] 
       vetor_yB[B] = vetor_y[i]
       B += 1
    elif vetor_x[i]<=600:
       vetor_xG[G] = vetor_x[i]
       vetor_yG[G] = vetor_v[i]
       G += 1
    elif vetor_x[i] <= 700:
       vetor_xR[R] = vetor_x[i]
       vetor_yR[R] = vetor_y[i]
       R += 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the @JohnGonidelis solution, initially gave an error of "name 'vector_xB' is not defined", so I added a "list ()" before the vectors. So the new bug is "'float' object is not iterable." Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: New question, new post. Please post the "float object not iterable"  problem with more details and some code on a new post ;)